# counting number of arithmetic sequenses of diff 1 of length of at least 2 that could be made from numbers {1,2,...,n}

Tags: combinatorics, arithmetic-progressions

im asked to find the number of arithmetic sequences of d=1 (or consecutive sequences the way the question describes it), of length of at least 2 from the numbers {1,2,...,n}. the question adds that it needs to be done by proving via bijection that this number is equal to the cardinality of a certain set.

the way i approached the question is: for sequences of length 2 i could start with one sequence 1,2 and slide across till it reaches n-1, so for every sequence of length x there will be n-x+1 sequences and then we sum for all values of x from 2 to n.

but this clearly isnt a bijection, the only bijection i could think of is a function that sends each x from 1 to n to the subgroup of seuneces of length x (represented as x-long vectors). but after that i get stuck, can someone guide me?

(i learn this course in a different language so excuse my mistakes)

Comment: Each arithmetic sequence with $d=1$ from the set $S=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ is uniquely identified by its starting number and its ending number. Can you count the cardinality of the set of all  pairs $(a,b)$ where $a\in S$, $b\in S$ and $a<b$?

Comment: that was helpful thank you!

Comment: @Zima Such an elegant response deserves to be made an answer to the question, which the original poster can then accept.

Answer (score 3):

Let $S$ and $B$ be defined as
$$ S=\{1,2,\dots,n\} \hspace{2cm} B=\{(a,b)|a,b\in S, a<b\}$$
Then the set $A$, of all arithmetic sequences with common difference $d=1$ and elements from $S$, is in bijection with the set $B$:
$$(x,x+1,x+2,\dots, y)\in A\longleftrightarrow (x,y)\in B$$
Therefore $|A|=|B|$, and the cardinality of $B$ can be immediately calculated:

$$|B|=\left|\{(1,m),m=2,\dots,n \}\right|+\left|\{(2,m),m=3,\dots,n \}\right|+\dots $$
$$\implies |B|=(n-1)+(n-2)+\dots+1=\frac{n(n-1)}{2} $$

Comment: $|B|$ is the solution to the very well studied handshake problem. Many posts on this site. Here's one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/621022/understanding-the-handshake-problem